# How does multiple threaded application works in multi processor system

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, multicore

Lets take we have a gaming application where a car, a bike and a tower clock runs in individual threads in parallel.

As we know only one thread runs at a time. (context switch happens between threads very fast which makes it look like it is running parallel to human eyes)

Lets assume the game is running in a dual core mobile phone.

Will the 3 threads be shared among by the two cores of the mobile processor?

is there any possibility for the car thread and bike thread to run simultaneously at any point of time ?

Comment: That's Operating System implementation details and also Game Engine implementation details. Generally speaking, it is possible but depends on what engine the game was build and on what OS you are running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any possibility for the car thread and bike thread to run simultaneously at any point of time?

Yes, there is a possibility. It depends on the JVM implementation (since you mentionned Java) and the OS implementation, so it's not garanteed, but it's possible.

> As we know only one thread runs at a time. (context switch happens between threads very fast which makes it look like it is running parallel to human eyes)

That's wrong. It would be true on a single core single processor, and could be true on some JVM/OS, but is wrong in the general case.

See [JLS chapter 17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html):

> Threads may be supported by having many hardware processors, by time-slicing a single hardware processor, or by time-slicing many hardware processors.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility for the car thread and bike thread to run simultaneously at any point of time?

Even on a single-core machine, it is possible for the threads to run *[concurrently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science))*. Running things concurrently is the whole point of using threads.

If you know that your program will only ever run on a single-processor platform, then you might be able to get away with disrespecting Java's *[memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model)*, But the basic rules of thread safety —what needs to be locked and what does not—will be the same in either case.

> ...and a tower clock

There is really no reason to use a dedicated thread to animate a clock. A clock is absolutely predictable. It's appearance is a function of the current time, and nothing else.

P.S.: In many applications, there's no reason to use dedicated threads for individual cars, bikes, or other MOBs either; but I don't know your application, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: On a single core, you can only execute one instruction at a time and I think that you are mixing things up here.  "Is there any possibility for the car thread and bike thread to run simultaneously at any point of time?" is not like "Can I have multiple threads running on a single core CPU?".

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov, I think we should avoid the word "simultaneous" in this conversation. It can mean either one of two different things. Let's say "concurrent" if we mean the one thing, and let's say "parallel" if we mean the other. I am not trying to override Etienne Miret's answer here: I just wanted to add something.  That is, if you're trying to prove that your program is "thread-safe", then it doesn't much matter whether the target platform has one processor or more than one. Most of the thread-safety issues are because of threads running _concurrently_.

Comment: I agree with you.